# Blazor Server Side Localization without cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, blazor-server-side

So Im trying to add Localization **without** a cookie to my Blazor Server Side project.

In the documentaition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#provide-ui-to-choose-the-culture it says:

*Use of a cookie ensures that the WebSocket connection can correctly propagate the culture. If localization schemes are based on the URL path or query string, the scheme might not be able to work with WebSockets, thus fail to persist the culture. Therefore, use of a localization culture cookie is the recommended approach.*

So I know its not recommended, but I would like it to be path-based anyway if possible. Can it be done with the standard services.AddLocalization(); and IStringLocalizer, or do I have to build a custom one?

Comment: According to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#provide-ui-to-choose-the-culture), The culture can be set using one of the following approaches: Cookies or Provide UI to choose the culture. If you want to use the Provide UI method to choose culture, you could follow the tutorial to configure the application.

Comment: @ZhiLv Yes? And the "Provide UI to choose the culture" is only a call to IActionResult SetCulture which sets a language cookie?

Answer (score 3):

For Localization, I prefer a direct, clear, and readable link that contains the language's first 2 letters (like: mysite.com/en/mypage ), which allows having the correct link using exactly the language needed.

The only solution I found that works perfectly with Blazor Server without the need for Cookies was using the package *"BlazorServerUrlRequestCultureProvider"* created by *"Pier-Luc Bonneville"*; it is effortless to use and gives excellent results.

**Usage:**

Install the package *BlazorServerUrlRequestCultureProvider* (worked perfectly for me  with .Net 5.0):

```
Install-Package BlazorServerUrlRequestCultureProvider -Version 1.0.0
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
using BlazorServerUrlRequestCultureProvider;
// ...
//------------------------------
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        // Set the Resources folder name:
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        // ...
    }
}
//------------------------------
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    #region Localization
    var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("ar"),
                };
    var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        // Select a default language:
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
        // For Numbers, Dates, etc:
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // For strings that we have localized in .resx files:
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    };
    app.UseUrlRequestLocalization(options);
    #endregion
    
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
}
```

**That was just all you need! No Cookies nor Controllers!**

Now use StringLocalizer as usual (in my case, the resource files names were App.resx and App.ar.resx inside the Resource folder):

**MyPage.razor:**

```
@page "/ar/MyPage"
@page "/en/MyPage"

@inject IStringLocalizer<App> localizer

<h1>@localizer["My Translated Text Here !"]</h1>
```

All Thanks & Credits goes to "Pier-Luc Bonneville" for his wonderful work. [Project Website](https://plbonneville.com/blog/url-based-localization-scheme-for-blazor-server/) , [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorServerUrlRequestCultureProvider/) .

--

**Bonus:**
To make your life much easier, use the tool **[ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager)**  to easily manage and translate resource files, it's a free and great tool, and it will save you a lot of time.